# Golang c-archive with libc instead of glibc

Tags: go, linker, cgo

Is it possible?

I have the following Go function I'd like to call from a C program:

```
// package name: test
package main

import "C"

//export Start
func Start() {
    println("Hello world")
}

func main() {
}
```

I'm using the following command to build the archive

`go build -buildmode=c-archive -o test.a main.go`

Using gcc I can get this C program working:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "test.h"

int main() {
  Start();
  return 0;
}
```

I'm using the following command to build the executable:

`gcc main.c sdlgotest.a -o main -lpthread`

This all works fine for amd64, but I'd like to use this archive in a aarch64 targed development environment (using [libtransistor](https://github.com/reswitched/libtransistor))

libtransistor build system uses LLVM but it has it's own set of standard includes (libc, etc.) and it doesn't use glibc.

So when I'm trying to get libtransistor to link my archive I get the following errors:

```
/usr/lib/llvm-5.0/bin/ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: stderr
>>> referenced by gcc_libinit.c:29
>>>               000006.o:(x_cgo_sys_thread_create) in archive ./sdlgotest.a

/usr/lib/llvm-5.0/bin/ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: stderr
>>> referenced by gcc_libinit.c:29
>>>               000006.o:(x_cgo_sys_thread_create) in archive ./sdlgotest.a
```

libtransistor by the way is compiling the code with flags like this:

`-nostdlib -nostdlibinc -isystem /opt/libtransistor/include/`

So I guess the problem is that the linker can't resolve those glibc symbols.

Is there a way to compile the Go runtime without those glibc symbols so I can use the archive like I intend to? (without relying on GCC toolchain or glibc)

Comment: Looking at https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/cgo/gcc_libinit.c#L29 it seems not easy to skip. Can you add some verbose/debug flag when linking to see if libc is actually included when linking? library order issue?

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/):

> The default C and C++ compilers may be changed by the `CC` and `CXX` environment variables, respectively; those environment variables may include command line options.

So I'd try something like

```
$ CC=clang go build -buildmode=c-archive -o test.a main.go
```

and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Run `go env` and see the list of env parameters set to go. You can change certain parameters based on what you need.

Following are some of the samples that I have used to build a shared dll from go program.

```
GOARCH=386 GOOS=windows CGO_ENABLED=1 GOPATH=`pwd` CC=i686-w64-mingw32-gcc  go build -o go-shared-lib.dll -buildmode=c-shared go-shared-libs
GOARCH=amd64 GOOS=windows CGO_ENABLED=1 GOPATH=`pwd` CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc  go build -o go-shared-lib.dll -buildmode=c-shared go-shared-libs
```